# Extract substrings from a string with a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

I'm trying to extract all substrings that start with ! for a string in Javascript. for example if my string is:

> Hi Jack !Smile, This is a !silly text to try out this !Code!

So the output should be an array with elements:

```
var arr = ['Smile', 'Silly', 'Code']
```

The reason I'm doing is because I want to convert these codes into emoticons for my chatroom and "!" is an indicator that this is an  emoticon code. Is there any fast and optimal to do this and not go through every word using a for loop?

Comment: Wat is `Array[]= {"Smile","silly","Code"}`? Array? Object? Array of Object?

Comment: Hirad, have you yourself tried looking up some regex?

Comment: @Tushar it's just an array of strings

Comment: @NikunjBanka I'm not familiar with regular expression but if that solves the issue I'll take a look into it

Comment: Then it should be `var arr = ['Smile', 'Silly', 'Code']`

Comment: @Tushar thanks, fixed it

Comment: @HiradRoshandel you need to look up Regex, it will solve this, it's also incredibly valuable to know in general.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw thanks Albert I'll take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rz530whm/1/ ?

Comment: @OP - You should give an actual example of what you are trying to do. With the example you gave we will be matching letters that come after an explanation point, with emoticons you may want symbols matched or something.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I'm exatcly doing what I mentioned above. Letters will come after !

Comment: @HiradRoshandel wonderful! Good luck :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple regex along with an array processing should do it

```js
var string = "Hi Jack !Smile, This is a !silly text to try out this !Code!";

var match = string.match(/!(.+?)\b/g),
  array = match ? match.map(function(val) {
    return val.substring(1)
  }) : [];

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(array))
```

```html
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex

```
!(.+?)\b
```